# How to target a specific part of a node title on XenForo with CSS?

Tags: css, xenforo

I'm trying to color a part of the node title with CSS. since XF doesn't allow you to use HTML in node titles without an Addon, this addon isn't the ideal route as some other addons that show node listings don't understand the HTML in the title and just displays it all which looks very very messy.

According to a person that I briefly spoke with, if I used the node ID in css and targeted the title it should work, but my knowledge of CSS is fairly limited and as such I don't really know how to begin this.

Could someone tell me how to do it? It's probably pretty simple but I've always struggled with understanding XF nodes in relation to css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color the whole node title use the code below.

```
.node_X .nodeTitle a {
    color: red;
}
```

Change `X` to your `node_id` and repeat the code for each node if you want different colors, if you want same color for multiple nodes then stack the classes like this:

```
.node_X .nodeTitle a,
.node_Y .nodeTitle a 
{
    color: red;
}
```

It's as easy as that, but if you want to color a few words from the node title then you need a custom development or try [this unmaintained add-on](https://xenforo.com/community/resources/th-html-in-node-titles-by-themehouse.2192/).